# Can a ruby Mustache lambda receive interpolated value?

Tags: ruby, mustache

With the ruby implementation of Mustache, I'm attempting to provide some numeric formatters by using lambdas.  What I would like to do is to receive the interpolated value and process that.  Here's an example similar to what I've been trying:

```
context = {
  products: [
    { name: 'Widget', price: 1.2 },
    { name: 'Cog', price: 0.75 }
  ],
  currency: ->(val) { '$' + BigDecimal(val).round(2) }
}

template = <<-EOF
  |Product|Price|
  {{#products}}
  |{{name}}|{{#currency}}{{price}}{{/currency}}|
  {{/products}}
EOF

Mustache.render(template, context)
```

What I'm hoping for is to have the currency lambda to be invoked with the price of the product.  Instead, I'm receiving `'{{price}}'`.  I tried to use `Mustache.render(val)` in the lambda but it does not (seem) to have the proper context to evaluate `'{{price}}'`

Any clues?

Comment: This is working for me, `Mustache.render("{{#y}}{{#x}}{{v}}{{/x}}{{/y}}", { x: ->(y) { y } , y: [{v: 1}, {v: 2}] })`

Comment: @maxpleaner, perhaps only because the string version looks like the numeric?  Try this: ```Mustache.render("{{#y}}{{#x}}{{v}}{{/x}}{{/y}}", { x: ->(y) { y.to_f } , y: [{v: 1}, {v: 2}] })
=> "0.00.0"```

Comment: OK yeah, I see your issue and have no idea how this works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking to do is add logic, so simplest thing to do is to just apply it:

```rb
context.each do |product|
  product[:price] = to_currency.call(product[:price])
end
```

However, I did look more deeply into this and found that what you can do is create a `Mustache` class:

```rb
class Product < Mustache
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name, price)
    @name, @price = name, price
  end

  def price
    currency(@price)
  end

  private

  def currency(price)
    num_str = BigDecimal(price.to_s).round(2).to_s('F')
    int, flt = num_str.split('.')
    "$#{[int, flt.ljust(2, '0')].join('.')}"
  end
end

template = <<-EOF
  |Product|Price|
  {{#products}}
  |{{name}}|{{price}}|
  {{/products}}
EOF

Mustache.render(template, products: [Product.new('Widget', 1.2), Product.new('Cog', 0.75)])
```

You can even dynamically pass blocks:

```rb
class Foo < Mustache
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def foo
    @block.call(2)
  end
end

tmp = <<~TMP
  Blah Blah
  blah {{foo}} blah
  Blah
TMP
foo = Foo.new { |x| (x + x).to_s + "asdf" }

foo.render(tmp)
Mustache.render(tmp, foo)
```

I'd never used Mustache before this, and I think the separation between logic and templating is great!

Comment: Thanks, @Kache.  While you answered the specific example, that example was a very simplified version of the issue that I'm dealing with that I contrived to illustrate a broader issue.  In context, I am providing a deeply nested hash and allowing customers to build their own templates, which rules out each of these possibilities.

More than likely, I will move on to handlebars which appears to be inspired by mustache but is a bit more amenable to helpers like what I'm after.

Comment: What? It doesn't "rule out the possibility" at all! The important takeaway is that any amount of logic/Ruby _is_ allowed in a `Moustache` subclass, meaning it can do anything a template helper would do.

Comment: You miss my point.  Yes, you can subclass Mustache and add any amount of custom logic.  There's no disagreement on that point.

That observation does nothing for the problem that I am trying to solve.  The templates in my system will be _user created_ and the data to be rendered is _deeply nested_.  I do not have the luxury of creating a custom pricing template with an external iterator because I cannot know if or when a user needs to work with that specific subset of the deeply nested data.  The last example suffers from the same kind of problem (I need multiple blocks but don't know when).